# Probability of rolling doubles more than once in ten rolls with a single a pair of dice?

Tags: probability, solution-verification

This is a question I made up just trying to practice probability calculations. I searched, but I didn't find any duplicates--most questions want to know probability of getting doubles once, or of getting an exact combination (I.e. snake eyes, or double sixes).

I came up with $.8385$.

My reasoning was: $P(\text{doubles})=6/36=1/6$, so $P(\text{not doubles})=5/6$. We have ten rolls, so the probabilty of not getting doubles more than once is $(5/6)^{10}=.1615$ so $P(\text{doubles more than once})=1-.1615=.8385$.

Is this the right answer, and if not, could someone help me understand where I went wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there, you also have to subtract the cases where we get exactly one double, as the question is asking for the probability of more than one double.

Now, $P(\text{one double}) = {10\choose 1} \cdot \left(\frac 16 \right)\cdot \left(\frac 56\right)^9 \approx 0.323$

and so the desired result is $0.8385-0.323=0.5155$.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this is a good example of a binomial random variable. Let $X$ be the number of doubles obtained in $10$ rolls of a pair of dice. So, the sample space of $X$ is $\{0,1,2,...10\}$. On any particular roll, the probability of rolling a double is $p=\frac{1}{6}$.
The binomial probability formula tells us that in $n$ trials, the probability of $k$ successes is $$\mathrm{P}( X=x) =\frac{n!}{( n-x) !x!} p^{x}( 1-p)^{n-x}$$
So in our case, $p=\frac{1}{6}$ and $n=10$. So the probability of at least $2$ doubles is $$\mathrm{P}( X\geq 2)=\sum ^{10}_{x=2}\frac{10!}{( 10-x) !x!}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{x}\left( 1-\frac{1}{6}\right)^{10-x}$$
Or equivalently, $$1-\sum ^{1}_{x=0}\frac{10!}{( 10-x) !x!}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{x}\left( 1-\frac{1}{6}\right)^{10-x}$$
So doing the calculations,
$$1-\left(\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{10} +10\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{9}\right)\approx 0.515.$$

Comment: K.defaoite - I like this approach, but I'm not following your math entirely. Would you mind showing your work? I tried to solve for the first equation and I came up with 90/2*1/36*(5/6)^9= 5/4*(5/6)^9=.242, which is not the right answer, so I'm obviously missing something. Thanks!!

Comment: @CBRF23 When you say first equation, do you mean the sum from $k=2$ to $k=10$?

Comment: I meant just the first equation at the top: nCk×p^k(1-p)^(n-k)

Comment: I see. Perhaps my usage of $p$ was a little confusing. $p$ denotes the probability of of a success on a single trial. I'll revise my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks. That definitely helps make things more clear. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I also want to add -  in my original answer I had the sample space of $X$ as $\{1,2,...10\}$ when it should instead be $\{0,1,2,...10\}$. Apologies for the confusion!